# Adding geom_point() to geom_hex()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a plot of hexbin data in R, in which the color represents the number of data points in each hexbin. I seem to have this working as is shown in the MWE below:

```
library(hexbin)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100), D=rnorm(100), E=rnorm(100))
maxVal = max(abs(data))
maxRange = c(-1*maxVal, maxVal)

x = data[,c("A")]
y = data[,c("E")]
h <- hexbin(x=x, y=y, xbins=5, shape=1, IDs=TRUE, xbnds=maxRange, ybnds=maxRange)
hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  hexID = h@cell, counts = h@count)

p <- ggplot(hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts, hexID=hexID)) + geom_hex(stat="identity") + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]), ylim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]))
```

[image: Resulting hexbin plot]

I am now trying to superimpose a subset of the original data in the form of points on top of the hexbin plot. I first create the subset of the original data as follows:

```
dat <- data[c(1:5),]
```

Then, I tried to plot these five data points onto the hexbin plot, p:

```
p + geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=A, y=B))
```

For which I receive the Error: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'counts' not found". I also tried the following:

```
p + geom_point() + geom_point(dat, aes(A, B))
```

For which I receive the Error: "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval".

I tried several new ideas based on similar posts - but would always have an error and no resulting plot. I am wondering if such a technique is possible. If anyone has ideas to share, I would very much appreciate your input!

Comment: Try this: `p + geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=A, y=B), inherit.aes = FALSE)`

Comment: Please read `?ggplot`, especially the Details section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, we need to set `inherit.aes = FALSE` in your `geom_point` call. Basically, you've set the `fill` aesthetic equal to `count` in your `ggplot` call, so when `ggplot` tries to add the points to the plot, it looks for `count` in `dat`. `ggplot` is telling you "hey, I can't find `count` in this data set, so I **can't** add that `geom` since it's missing an aes".

```
p + geom_point(data = dat, aes(x=A, y=B),
               inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

[image]

Or, we could define `p` as:

```
p <- ggplot() + 
    geom_hex(data = hexdf, aes(x=x, y=y, fill = counts), stat="identity") + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]), ylim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]))
```

And then we wouldn't need `inhert.aes`:

```
p + geom_point(data = dat, aes(x = A, y = B))
```

Comment: Thanks @bouncyball - especially for posting two solutions. Comparing the two solutions is helping me to see the root of the problem  more clearly now.

Comment: That's good to hear. I would also echo @Henrik's advice to read the 'Details' section of `?ggplot`